# ¿Por qué no me corre el código al ejecutarlo de está manera?

Tags: python, script, github

clone un paquete de git hub con el fin de correr un código pero me salta al final cuando quiero ejecutarlo desde colab un error de sintaxis. Si me dan una mano con esto me vendía genial, gracias.[image: Captura de pantalla]

Comment: Sugiero que si conoces a alguien que le funcione veas qué versión tiene y cómo lo está usando. Sino deberías ponerte en contacto con el creador.

Comment: Asegúrate de seguir [los pasos para instalarlo](https://asteca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).